# Pass message from ChildViewController toParentViewController before ParentViewController's delegate methods are called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

**Scenario:**
I have 2 VC -

**ChildViewController**
It has a tableView which displays a list of items. I need to pass the `tableView.contentSize.height` value, after the table is populated to my ParentVC. For that I am using delegate as

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableVieww.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellreuse", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "heyy"

        hght.constant = tableVieww.contentSize.height
        if flag == true
        {
           delegate.tableHeight(tableVieww.contentSize.height)
           print(tableVieww.contentSize.height)
           flag = false
        }
        return cell
    }
```

**ParentViewController**

It has a tableView with one cell. This cell is showing view of a childVC i.e nwVC. I want to change the cell height depending upon the height of my ChildVC's tableView.

I am adding the childVC's view by the following code & I know this is the wrong place to do so but I am not getting how,where and what to do, to get the childViewController's function to be called before the ParentViewController's functions?

```
vc3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nwVC") as? nwVC//newVC is ChildViewController
    vc3!.view!.frame = cell.myview.bounds
    vc3!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    cell.myview.addSubview(vc3!.view)//UIView inside the cell
    vc3!.delegate=self
```

**Problem** -

*The delegate methods of ParentViewController's tableView gets called before the childViewController's function's are called for which I cannot update my rowHeight as per the childVC's table content.*

Comment: what does `delegate.tableHeight` do when it is called?

Comment: @sken3r.MI Tha is the delegate method & it just passes the height of the table view to the parentViewController after populating it with contents.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I figured out something that works but still I want suggestions from iOS dev's viewing this question.

**Mark:** *I could not perform the loading of childVC's functions before the loading of ParentVC's table view delegate functions* but I did something which works quite good.

**In my ParentVC's**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        vc3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nwVC") as? nwVC
        addChildViewController(vc3!)
        vc3!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        vc3!.delegate=self
}

//childVC's delegate function implementation
func tableHeight(height: CGFloat) { 
        height = height//I get the table view height from the childVC,height is a variable declared as var height = 200.0(it can be any value > 0)
        print(ht)
        self.tableVIeww.reloadData()//reload my tableView
 }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return hgt//at first call it returns the default value but in the 2nd call it returns the value sent by childVC
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableVIeww.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellreuse", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myTVC
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        vc3?.view.frame = cell.myview.bounds
        cell.myview.addSubview((vc3?.view)!)//myView is the view in the cell's content view pinned to its edges.

        return cell
}
```

**Pro's & Con's**

*Pro's*

The biggest advantage is that you get the works to be done.

*Con's*

As you can see that ChildVC's view is added 2 times (1 with the default cell size of height variable & the 2nd time when the table reloads). I feel that this might hamper the performance slightly & if Data is dynamic it might process for a bit long.

**Please feel free to suggest...**